# Why does the `syntax` command get weird with string variables in Stata?

Tags: stata

Let's say I make the following simple program:

```
program define test_prog1
    syntax varname =exp
    display `"`varlist' `exp'"'
end
```

And I run it with the following commands in the Stata interpreter, where I already have variables in the workspace:

```
. gen a=_n
. tostring a, replace
a was float, now str6
. test_prog1 a="aaa"
type mismatch
```

What?  It's a variable followed by an expression, what type is there to mismatch when I didn't specify a type in my `syntax` command?  And even if I do specify `varname(string)` or `varname(str#)` it doesn't help--and even if it did, for the real program I'm trying to write I want to work regardless of whether `varname` is string or numeric.

How do I get my program to accept either numeric or string variables in `varname`, and not blow up when it's given a `="string_constant"` expression?

Comment: I am puzzled at what you expect the program to do. If your only issue is understanding what `syntax` does here, then fine: what the program does is irrelevant.

Comment: The `program` is a minimal example which reproduces the error I see.   Because `a` is an existing variable and `="aaa"`  is an expression, my program should display `a="aaa"` and exit, but it errors on `syntax`   Though now I'm looking at it I'm missing some quotes (which don't matter since it errors before it gets there but still) let me just add those...

Comment: If you want that text to be shown, you will need compound double quotes.

Comment: Yes I already editted to fix that.   Again, that doesn't really make a difference to my question, which is about the error that happens immediately prior to the `display` line, but the code example given is fixed. The error happens with our without proper quoting in the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pdf manual says exp must be numeric:

[image]

I am not sure if there is a way to shoehorn this into `syntax` or `args`, but this would get you close:

```
set obs 3
gen a =_n
tostring a, gen(b)

capture program drop test_prog1    
program define test_prog1
    gettoken varname rest : 0, parse(" =")
    confirm variable `varname'
    display `"`varname'"'
    display `"`rest'"'  
end

test_prog1 a=3
test_prog1 b="3"
test_prog1 c =4
```

Comment: What version of Stata are you using?   If I look in `help syntax` it says absolutely nothing about `exp` needing to be numeric.   I'm on Stata 16.1

Comment: Also, I think the way to shoehorn it into `syntax` would be to use `anything(equalok)` though it begs the question of "what is the point of `syntax` if it won't actually parse basic Stata syntax?"

Comment: There are many points to `syntax`, so that is, to be frank, a silly question. The much more specific question of _why in this context an expression must be numeric_ is in contrast good and best directed at StataCorp, as I doubt any user-programmer is able to answer it.

Comment: The latest manual entry for `syntax` is accessible to anyone with internet access at https://www.stata.com/manuals/psyntax.pdf regardless of whether they have to access to (the latest version of) Stata. I don't think `syntax` has changed much if at all recently, but it could be that StataCorp has documented this rule since 16.1 in response to questions like yours.

Comment: I have 17. The anything() approach will still require parsing since you can't combine it with varname, so I am not sure what the benefit is of this on top of what I did. The tradeoff with `syntax` is that ease entails some inflexibility. If you were willing to stick the value into an option instead of in the first part with "=", that would be much easier.

Comment: The basic minimum reproduction example only has `varname =exp` in it for clarity, but in my real code I'm going to want `[if]`, `[in]`, and other `[, option]` inputs that I would prefer to keep separate, thus `anything()` is the way to go.   Sticking the expression into an option is very much not preferred.